# Code School Screencast - Rails App From Scratch - Part 1 Error: Couldn't find Trip with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following codeschool.com's ruby screencast on making an app and ran into this error.

Full error is

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DestinationsController#show
>
> Couldn't find Trip with 'id'=

**The error applies to the @trip instance below**

```
GET /destinations/1.json   
def show
@trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
```

Here is the applicable code from the destinations_controller.rb:

```
 def show
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
    @destination = Destination.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Here is the Trip model

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :destinations
end
```

And the Destination model

```
class Destination < ActiveRecord::Base

        belongs_to :trip
    end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :destinations

  resources :trips do 
    resources :destinations
  end

  root to: 'trips#index'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. :) :) :)

**Update 1**: From log files

> Started GET "/destinations/4" for ::1 at 2016-03-31 00:50:08 +0900
>   Processing by DestinationsController#show as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"id"=>"4"}
>
> [1m[35mDestination Load (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT  "destinations".* FROM
>   "destinations" WHERE "destinations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
>
> [1m[36mTrip Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "trips".* FROM "trips"
>   WHERE "trips"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", nil]]
>
> Completed 404 Not Found in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Trip with 'id'=):
>   app/controllers/destinations_controller.rb:14:in `show'*

**Update 2** : the destinations_controller in its entirety.

```
class DestinationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_destination, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /destinations
  # GET /destinations.json
  def index
    @destinations = Destination.all
  end

  # GET /destinations/1
  # GET /destinations/1.json
  def show
    Rails.logger.debug params.inspect
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
    @destination = Destination.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /destinations/new
  def new
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
    @destination = Destination.new
  end

  # GET /destinations/1/edit
  def edit
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
    @destination = Destination.find(set_destination)
  end

  # POST /destinations
  # POST /destinations.json
  def create
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
    @destination = @trip.destinations.new(destination_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @destination.save
        format.html { redirect_to trip_destination_path(@trip, @destination), notice: 'Destination was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @destination }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @destination.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /destinations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /destinations/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @destination.update(destination_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @destination, notice: 'Destination was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @destination }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @destination.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /destinations/1
  # DELETE /destinations/1.json
  def destroy
    @destination.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to destinations_url, notice: 'Destination was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_destination
      @destination = Destination.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def destination_params
      params.require(:destination).permit(:name, :description)
    end
end
```

Comment: you are probably not sending params[:trip_id] with your request

Comment: In that show action, `puts params.inspect` to see what params are being passed. `trip_id` is not being passed as a param in your case.

Comment: You'll have to show more information relevant to :trip_id for us to be able to help.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I have updated the post with info from the log file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right ... the only parameter being passed is :id ... there is no :trip_id in your parameter collection.

Comment: How would I fix it. Sorry newbie here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the show action to this:

```
def show
  @trip = @destination.trip
end
```

Edit: Removed `@destination` assignment here because of the before_action running set_destination.

The `Destination` model has one `Trip`:

```
class Destination < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
end
```

Since you're setting the `@destination` because `id` is actually passed over, you can just get `@trip` through association.

Comment: thank you! It worked! I am still trying to wrap my head around this: _"Since you're setting the @ destination because id is actually passed over, you can just get @ trip through association."_

Comment: So we know that the `id` parameter is being passed over, but the `trip_id` parameter is not. We're using `id` to set `@destination` within the `show` action (method). Since we know that `Destination` belongs to one `Trip`, we don't need the `trip_id`. We can get to the only `Trip` that `@destination` has through association: `@destination.trip`.

Answer (score 1):

In your routes you currently have a nested route for destinations:

```
resources :trips do 
  resources :destinations
end
```

This means a destination is expected to be accessed in the context of its trip.

e.g. `GET /trips/1/destinations/1.json` where you'll have a `trip_id` parameter for the trip and an `id` parameter for the id of the destination.

You're also defining an non-nested route for destinations:

```
resources :destinations
```

but your `DestinationController's` show action assumes the nested version is being used when it does:

```
@trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
@destination = Destination.find(params[:id])
```

Have a check that the `GET` request matches what's being shown in the screencast - or post a link to the exact screencast you're following.

Comment: Thank you mikej. https://www.codeschool.com/screencasts/rails-app-from-scratch-part-1 but I think it is behind a paywall. Posting it in case you have an account.